# Move command to the beginning or end of the paragraph

Tags: macros, floats, paragraphs

I have a macro that replaces a word in the middle of the paragraph and figure (inside a wrapfigure environment). But the text justification looks awful and it seems to be because wrapfigure cannot be used in the middle of the text (as pointed out here: [Wrapping images in text without inducing ugly justified text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/97871/wrapping-images-in-text-without-inducing-ugly-justified-text)). I would like to move the wrapfigure to the beginning or end of the paragraph.

In other words. Currently, this:

```
This is a \mycommand{long} text.
```

becomes:

```
This is a \textbf{long}\begin{wrapfigure}...\end{wrapfigure} text.
```

but should be:

```
\begin{wrapfigure}...\end{wrapfigure}
This is a \textbf{long} text.
```

Comment: Your best bet would be to use \everypar to implement the wrapficure and use the aux file to communicate.   This won't be easy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works, but I'm not sure if fiddling with `\everypar` can break something, specially when used inside lists:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\newtoks\oldeverypar
\def\insertedfigure{\fbox{Inserted figure or whatever}\everypar=\oldeverypar\par}
\def\mycommand#1{\textbf{#1}\oldeverypar=\everypar\everypar={\insertedfigure}}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[66]

\lipsum*[66] This is \mycommand{another} test. \lipsum[66]

\lipsum[66]

\end{document}
```

Basically, `\mycommand` puts its argument in boldface and stores in `\everypar` the token which will expand into the required figure (which will be output when the current paragraph is finished). It also saves the current value of `\everypar`, and restores it after the figure is output.

The result for this example is:

[image: Result]

Another example, closer to your question, is providing the following definition for `\insertedfigure`:

```
\def\insertedfigure{%
\begin{wrapfigure}{R}{0.5\textwidth}
\centerline{\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image}}
\caption{Example figure}
\end{wrapfigure}%
\everypar=\oldeverypar\par}
```

Which produces:

[image: Result]

However, as you can see, this makes the figure to appear in the next paragraph, which I guess is not ok, despite the question title.

Comment: One can't use `wrapfig` in lists anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Simply include as second argument of `\mycommand` the rest of the paragraph,  i.e.:

```
This is a \mycommand{long}{text.}
```

Then you can format `#1` as bold, then just write `#2\par` and finally the wrapfigure, without the any magic  TeX.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{wrapfig,graphicx}

\def\mycommand#1#2{\textbf{#1} #2\par
\begin{wrapfigure}{R}{0.35\linewidth}
\centering\includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{Example figure}
\end{wrapfigure}\par}

\def\a{This is the first paragraph. }

\def\b{This is another long paragraph. }

\begin{document}

This is a \mycommand{long}{text. \a\a\a\a\a\a\a}

\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b

\end{document}
```

However, with or wihout `\everypar`, this not ensure that the wrapfigure is placed in a good position. I see little advantage of this macro over another with only the figure that is moved manually as needed in the final draft.