# Let LaTeX decide where to place figures

Tags: floats, positioning

There are too many posts that complains LaTeX is not doing a good enough job in placing floats such as figures, and ways to work around them (`[!htbp]`, `\usepackage{float}`, etc.). Upon curiosity I cannot help thinking it the other way around. If I **am satisfied** with the mechanism that LaTeX position the floats and I know exactly which figures I want to appear "here" (the first time they are referenced), which I am happy to place on the top of the pages, and which I am happy even if they appear on a separate page, and that I am feeling lazy (in the sense that I want LaTeX to make the decisions for me),

**Is there a way to put the source code for all the floats (you may restrict the discussion to figures if you like) in a tex file that is to be `\input` or `\include`ed, with all the necessary position specifiers given, and let LaTeX automatically insert them where appropriate by referencing them?**

Side question: I don't understand why people should use floats at all if they are using the `[H]` specifier of the `float` package.

**Edit**: I prefer pure LaTeX solutions but I don't mind learning something new if solutions in LuaLaTeX or alike are given.

**Edit 2**: The current implementation I have in mind is closely related to [Move command to the beginning or end of the paragraph](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/270044/move-command-to-the-beginning-or-end-of-the-paragraph).

Comment: I believe the use of [H] is to allow the use of \caption instead of \captionof (or `\def\@captype{figure}`).  Either that or they don't quite understand what the figure and table environments are for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, this can be implemented easily.

```
\documentclass{article}

% for example images
\usepackage{mwe}

% xparse is no necessary but allows a more flexible interface design
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{graphics}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand\placefig{m O{} m m}{%
    \begin{figure}%
        \centering
        \includegraphics[#2]{#3}%
        \caption{#4}%
        \label{#1}%
    \end{figure}%
}
\NewDocumentCommand\deffig{m O{} m m}{
    \expandafter\gdef\csname fig@r@#1\endcsname{%
        \placefig{#1}[#2]{#3}{#4}%
        \expandafter\global\expandafter\let\csname fig@r@#1\endcsname\relax
    }%
}
\let\old@ref\ref
\renewcommand*\ref[1]{%
    \old@ref{#1}%
    \ifcsname fig@r@#1\endcsname\csname fig@r@#1\endcsname\fi
}
\makeatother

% define the (possible) figures
\deffig{fig:ex-a}[width=.5\textwidth]{example-image-a}{This is an example image.}
\deffig{fig:ex-b}{example-image-b}{This is another example image.}

\begin{document}

This is the first reference to fig.~\ref{fig:ex-a} in the document.

Here, we reference fig.~\ref{fig:ex-a} again.

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the example.]

If you use packages that modify the referencing mechanism (like `hyperref`), you will have to adjust the modification of `\ref` accordingly.

Beware that references are allowed in locations where floats are not (e.g. inside tables). You can add more commands to allow placing a defined float without referencing it to circumvent this problem.

If you do not wish all your floats to follow one pattern (given by `\placefig`), you could modify `\deffig` to allow direct input of the float environment.

However, given these caveats, I am unsure of the usefulness of this approach. But I guess you can decide that for yourself.